# Circular loading animation (like Weather Channel App)

Tags: ios, objective-c, loading-animation

How would I implement a loading animation like the one found in the **Weather Channel iOS App**?

Specifically, I have a rounded `UIButton` that I want a spinning circle around when the user has tapped it, and something is loading.

Preferably, I'd want to make this using a built-in iOS framework, and as few 3rd party libraries as possible.

Here's how the Weather Channel Application looks like (couldn't get a gif, so to see it in action download the application from the App Store):

[image: Screenshot of Weather Channel iOS App]

It doesn't necessarily have to look exactly like this, a solid color would be a good start. But the concept should be the same. I don't believe it should be hard to make, but sadly I have no idea where to start.

Thanks for all help!

**EDIT 1:**
I should point out that a solid color is good enough, and it doesn't need a gradient or a glow.

I have been working on some simple code that might be in the right direction. Please feel free to use that as a starting point:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  // Make the button round
  self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0;
  self.clipsToBounds = YES;

  // Create the arc
  CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2) radius:(self.frame.size.width / 2) startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:NO].CGPath;
  circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  circle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
  circle.lineWidth = 10;

  // Create the animation

  // Add arc to button
  [self.layer addSublayer:circle];
}
```

Comment: Do **not** create layers or animations or modify the layer hierarchy inside of `drawRect:`! It's for drawing _only_.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist It's for testing purposes only, I'd be doing this as a reaction to a button-press normally.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out elsewhere, you can just add a view, and the rotate it. If you want to rotate with block-based animation, it might look like:

```
- (void)rotateView:(UIView *)view {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:(CGFloat) i / 4.0 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat) (i + 1) * M_PI / 2.0);
                }];
            }
        } completion:nil];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Frankly, while I generally prefer block-based animation, the silliness of wrapping an animation with an animation (which is necessary to get no ease-in/ease-out) makes the block-based approach less compelling. But it illustrates the idea.

---

Alternatively, in iOS 7 and later, you could use UIKit Dynamics to spin it:

1. Define a property for the animator:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
   ```
2. Instantiate the animator:

   ```
   self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
   ```
3. Add rotation to an item:

   ```
   UIDynamicItemBehavior *rotationBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.imageView]];
   [rotationBehavior addAngularVelocity:2.0 forItem:self.imageView];
   [self.animator addBehavior:rotationBehavior];
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you here. Are you suggesting I put a slightly larger rounded view behind my button, and then just rotate that around its center?

I haven't tried it yet, but I don't quite see how that will lead to the animation I want: Let's say I have a half circle, I want to be spinning around the edges of my button. I have seen multiple loading animations like this, but I cannot find any to illustrate my idea right now better than the Weather Channel App. 

In short: I don't want my entire button spinning, only a small path around it.

Comment: @Alekplay You can create a separate image view with just the highlighted arc, place this over the existing button image, but use transparency to let the button underneath show through. Then rotate this separate image view.

Comment: I see, I'll try that :) But let's say I wanted a slightly more "dynamic" approach (size of the button depends on size of the device). How could I "draw" this arc around my button, and then just rotate that around its center? (just a solid color is good enough)

Comment: Yes, a solid color is good enough :) Would you mind updating your answer with an example how I could use that to rotate an simple solid color arc around my button? I'll update my question with some code I've been working on as well :)

Comment: @Alekplay Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68352/discussion-between-rob-and-alekplay).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I miss something but I think you only need to rotate a custom spin asset.

You can easily achieve this with a method like:

```
- (void) runSpinAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration repeat:(float)repeat;
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

You need to repeat it indefinitely. So put `HUGE_VALF` as repeat parameter.

And if you want to create a custom spin image according to your button size, you can use bezier path. For example, you can do something like:

```
-(UIImageView*)drawBezierPathInView:(UIView*)view{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height));

    //this gets the graphic context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //you can stroke and/or fill
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1.f].CGColor);

    CGFloat lineWidth = 8.f;
    UIBezierPath *spin = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [spin addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width * 0.5f, view.frame.size.height * 0.5f) radius:view.frame.size.width * 0.5f - lineWidth * 0.5f startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:2 * M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [spin setLineWidth:lineWidth];
    [spin stroke];

    //now get the image from the context
    UIImage *bezierImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *bezierImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bezierImage];
    return bezierImageView;
}
```

And you create your button like:

```
// myButton is your custom button. spinView is an UIImageView, you keep reference on it to apply or to stop animation
self.spinView = [self drawBezierPathInView:mybutton];
[mybutton addSubview:self.spinView];
[self runSpinAnimationOnView:self.spinView duration:3 repeat:HUGE_VALF];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm actually working with something similar right now. 

But I would need something **to rotate** right? Something to put around my rounded button? Something like a `CAShapeLayer` or alike? I don't want my entire button rotating, only a small line around it. How would I do that?

Comment: First create your button. Then create an imageView with tour spin and add it on your button. Apply the animation on the image view and voilà. As Rob suggest it, you can also create only a layer and apply the animation on it.

Comment: Let's say I didn't want to use an image. How could I achieve this in a more "dynamic" way (the size of the button depends on the screen-size of the device)? Is there a way where I can draw an arc around my `UIButton` and then just rotate that around its center? (to clarify, just a solid color is good enough)

Comment: what if you add a border with the preferred colour to your button only on the one of the sides ... I think That when you corner radius it it may look like an arc ... :) Or try to use image as a border (not sure if it is possible .. just an idea ... )